# Compositing effects does not show in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I've been trying to render this animation, but the compositing "glow" effect does not show even after I apply the nodes. Can someone tell me how I could fix this problem? Or even better, could someone render the animation and send it to me so I can make sure my computer isn't the problem? File: https://pasteall.org/blend/0734274268084d0a8f53002207a91452

I've tried rendering multiple times and even video editor

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to plug the *Glare* node into the *Composite* node, otherwise the effect won't be seen in final render:

[image]